# Print subform results

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm having troubles with creating Report for printing subform records in Access. Problem is that I have unbound subform on my form, and this subform .Recordsource is based upon dynamic SQL string. Here is my code for that (just a sample for better understanding):

```
Private Sub SearchRecords_Click()

Dim SQL As String

On Error Resume Next

SQL = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE 1=1"

If Not IsNull(Txt1) Then
SQL = SQL & " AND MyTableField1 =[Forms]![Form1]![Txt1]"
End If

If Not IsNull(Txt2) Then
SQL = SQL & " AND ((MyTableField2 LIKE ""*" & Txt2 & "*""))"
End If

DoCmd.OpenForm "Form2", acNormal

Forms![Form2]![MySubform].Form.RecordSource = SQL

End Sub
```

As you see, this code is used to open Form2, where subform is, and It displays results from DB as User wants them. Now, what I want is that this subform result would be also printed (not printscreen, a report).

I've created a Report based on table that holds all this neccessary records, and tried with this, but It doesn't work :

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "ReportNameHere", acViewPreview, WhereCondition:="[PKFieldNameHere]=" & Me.SubformControlName.Form.ControlNameHere
```

What must I do, I can't find any example of something like I need, can somebody please help me ??

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer. I just had to reference Report in Load_event to .Recordsource of my Subform. Sorry for bothering.